# Create Marketing Cloud DE Using SOAP API in Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I haven't been having luck with using the FuelSDKs to use the Marketing Cloud APIs. So I've been trying to test the SOAP API directly in postman first to see if it works; and sadly I haven't gotten that to work either...

I pretty much copied and pasted the SOAP request from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm) but it doesn't work. I get a `400 Bad Request`

### Details

First I get an access token by authenticating against `https://domain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token/`

```json
{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "clientid",
"client_secret": "secret",
"scope": "data_extensions_read data_extensions_write"
}
```

This seems to work fine, I get the access token, which I use in the following request, which I copied verbatim from the link above.

I send the request to `https://domain.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:header>
  <fueloauth>
    access_token
  </fueloauth>
</s:header>
<s:body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options></Options>
        <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension">
            <CustomerKey>DataExtensionFromAPI</CustomerKey>
            <Name>DataExtensionFromAPI</Name>
            <IsSendable>false</IsSendable>
            <SendableDataExtensionField>
                <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
            </SendableDataExtensionField>
            <SendableSubscriberField>
                <Name>Email Address</Name>
                <Value></Value>
            </SendableSubscriberField>
            <Fields>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>ChannelUser</Name>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>ChannelUser_EmailAddress</Name>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>Demographic_Address_Key</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>Demographic_Address</Name>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</s:body>
</s:envelope>
```

However I seem to get this `400 Bad Request` as a response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after to the edit EazyE suggested, the request from that page was throwing another error:

> "The SendableSubscriberField cannot be EmailAddress because the SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has been turned on" when creating a new Data Extension.

So this is the final request, with headers: `Content-Type: text/xml` and `SOAPAction: Create`

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header> 
    <fueloauth>token</fueloauth> 
  </soapenv:Header> 
  <soapenv:Body> 
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"> 
      <Options></Options> 
      <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension"> 
        <CustomerKey>DataExtensionTesting</CustomerKey> 
        <Name>DataExtensionTesting</Name> 
        <IsSendable>true</IsSendable> 
        <SendableDataExtensionField> 
          <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey> 
          <Name>EmailAddress</Name> 
          <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType> 
        </SendableDataExtensionField> 
        <SendableSubscriberField> 
          <Name>Subscriber Key</Name> 
          <Value/> 
        </SendableSubscriberField> 
        <Fields> 
          <Field> 
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/> 
            <CustomerKey>SubscriberKey</CustomerKey> 
            <Name>SubscriberKey</Name> 
            <FieldType>Text</FieldType> 
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired> 
            <IsPrimaryKey>true</IsPrimaryKey> 
            <MaxLength>100</MaxLength> 
          </Field> 
          <Field> 
            <CustomerKey>TestField1</CustomerKey> 
            <Name>TestField1</Name> 
            <FieldType>Text</FieldType> 
          </Field> 
          <Field> 
            <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey> 
            <Name>EmailAddress</Name> 
            <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType> 
          </Field> 
          <Field> 
            <CustomerKey>Name</CustomerKey> 
            <Name>Name</Name> 
            <FieldType>Text</FieldType> 
          </Field> 
          <Field> 
            <CustomerKey>ImageURL</CustomerKey> 
            <Name>ImageURL</Name> 
            <FieldType>Text</FieldType> 
          </Field> 
        </Fields> 
      </Objects> 
    </CreateRequest> 
  </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Validating your call in SoapUI it appears your syntax is wrong in the envelope/header/body tag. They should be capitalized

Similar to

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="xsi">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth>access_token</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
```

And corresponding closing tags

Comment: I think that might be partially it.